# HTML/javascript- string append with variable to bind onclick button event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, string, append

For a HTML button element i want to bind the below onclick event

`<a class="btn btn-sm btn-bitbucket" id="test" onclick="document.location.href='https://192.22.32.101/V0_3_4/cgi-bin/config.cgi'">`

The above one works fine and the cgi got executed perfect . But the requirement is i want to replace "https://192.22.32.101/V0_3_4/cgi-bin/config.cgi"
with a varible since this is dynamic . Can someone provide the java script. Like the below.

HTML

```
<a class="btn btn-sm btn-bitbucket" id="test"> .
```

JAVA SCRIPT

```
document.getElementById("test").onclick = "document.location.href="HOST_CGI_PATH""; (I am facing difficulties defining the correct quotes)
```

I am doing this binding in document ready function.Here the HOST_CGI_PATH is a javascript variable refers to the actual path.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do

```
document.getElementById("test").onclick = function(){ 
     document.location.href=HOST_CGI_PATH;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're overcomplicating it:

```
document.getElementById("test").href = HOST_CGI_PATH;
```